# Undefined reference in Linux makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I want to build my application under linux but i can't get my makefile to make it.
the problems are the static libraries I wan to link with. I get a lot of "undefined reference to" error messages like:

```
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
```

or

```
undefined reference to `cgicc::Cgicc::Cgicc(cgicc::CgiInput*)'
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CXX = gcc

INCL_CGICC = ../cgicc-3.2.9
INCL_OPENSSL = ../openssl-1.0.0e/include
INCL_LOG4CPLUS = ../log4cplus-1.0.4/include
INCL_BOOST = ../boost_1_46_1
INCLUDES = -I$(INCL_CGICC) -I$(INCL_OPENSSL) -I$(INCL_LOG4CPLUS) -I$(INCL_BOOST)

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -D_LINUX -DVERSNUM=2 -DVERSMAJOR=0 -DVERSMINOR=0 $(INCLUDES)

TARGET = myapp
OBJS = Main.o 

all: $(TARGET)
strip -s $<
mv -f $< release 

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
$(CXX) -static -o $@ $(OBJS) \
            ../cgicc-3.2.9/cgicc/.libs/libcgicc.a \
            ../openssl-1.0.0e/libssl.a \
            ../openssl-1.0.0e/libcrypto.a \
            ../log4cplus-1.0.4/src/.libs/liblog4cplus.a \
            -ldl -lpthread

%.o: %.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

The problem is that I have no idea of makefiles. I just copied an existing one and tried to adjust it. Didn't seem to work, and I can't find an example makefile that includes static libraries.

Comment: The makefile is all fine and well. The only mistake you are making is that you use C compiler to compile and link C++. The C++ compiler is called `g++` (they are actually the same except for a few defaults, which is why it *almost* works).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't need the `%.o: %.cpp` rule, since make has one built in. It's almost the same, but it also includes `$(CPPFLAGS)` (C preprocessor flags). So unless you're deliberately excluding those, you'll get a more "idiomatic" makefile if you just use the implicit rule. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html is a jolly good read. The couple of hours it takes to slog through the important bits will be repaid via less time staring at makefiles in disbelief within, oh, about 4 hours :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`CXX = gcc`

You're linking with `gcc`, rather than `g++`, so `-lstdc++` is not linked in by default.
Note that using `gcc` to compile C++ sources work just fine, since `g++` is called implicitly in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have no clue about writing Makefiles, perhaps you should have a look at some of the Makefile generators, e.g. autotools, cmake etc. These are much easier to use in my opinion, and, once you master their use, much more powerful.